# Jetpack Compose Constraint Layout constrains not linking

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-compose-layout

I'm using constrainAs with Jetpack Compose to constrain a list of wifi options to the top of the parent and then to the bottom of a text view. As seen from the photo my list isn't being constrained to the top of the parent or to the textview below it, and it is even being pushed off the screen upwards?

For reference 'list' is the list of wifi options, and 'text1' is the textview that starts with "Select your wifi"

[image]

```
@Composable
fun ScanWifiScreen(wifiList: List<WifiOption>, onClick: (WifiOption) -> Unit) {
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(colorResource(id = R.color.background))
) {

    val (list, text1, text2, progressIndicator) = createRefs()

    WifiList(
        wifiOptions = wifiList,
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(list) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 8.dp)
                bottom.linkTo(text1.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.background))
            .fillMaxHeight())

    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.select_wifi),
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
            .constrainAs(text1) {
                bottom.linkTo(text2.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            },
        style = TextStyle(
            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksand_regular)),
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.main_text),
            letterSpacing = 0.22.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            lineHeight = 32.sp
        )
    )
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.cant_see_network),
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
            .constrainAs(text2) {
                bottom.linkTo(progressIndicator.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            },
        style = TextStyle(
            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksand_regular)),
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.sub_text),
            letterSpacing = 0.18.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            lineHeight = 24.sp
        )
    )

    ProgressIndicator2(
        progression = 3,
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(progressIndicator) {
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
        })
   }
}
```

Comment: Add `top.linkTo(parent.top)` to make `text1` stick to the top of the screen and `top.linkTo(text1.bottom)` for `list` to be below `text1`

Comment: this would make the list below text1, I need the list above text1

Comment: for `list` -- `top.linkTo(parent.top)` and for `text1` -- `top.linkText(link.bottom)`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your List remove the `.fillMaxHeight()` modifier and add the constraint  `height = Dimension.fillToConstraints`

```
 WifiList(
     //....
     modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(list) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 8.dp)
                bottom.linkTo(text1.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
            }
      )
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: I think that Dimension.fillToConstraints should be the default value to this attribute... Because is the default behavior of the ConstraintLayout on view system.

Comment: I honestly will never understand why google makes everything so complicated and and unintuitive

Comment: Missing `height = Dimension.fillToConstraints` was my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Renascienza it's not default value. You set `wrap_content` or `0dp` (Dimension.fillToConstraints) in view system for height or width, the same behavior is here